# Timer Task Execute wrong time delay

Tags: android

My app started automatic when device is Restart or Manually turnoff.
in this app i am changing imageView image after every 25 second and its working fine. 
**But when i restart mobile device and app start automatic
then some image wait for 25 second but some images change after 1 or 2 second.**
Please Help

Here is code--->

```
i = 0;

    Timer slideTimer = new Timer();

    slideTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (i >= imageBitmapList.size()){
                        i = 0;// resert value
                    }

                    try {

                            img_vw2.setImageBitmap(imageBitmapList.get(i));

                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }

                    i++;
                }
            });

        }

    }, 0, 25000);
```

Comment: Is this running in an activity? In what lifecycle method? And is the activity started from a boot receiver!?

Comment: yes true. Check your activity life cycle.

Comment: yes.  this is an activity. and its started from boot receiver.